# Android JSON Get via HttpURLConnection error 405

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

so I'm trying to do a GET Request to my web service, and since I saw that the HttpGet class is being deprecated, I try to use the HttpURLConnection class instead, and I used it successfully with a 'POST' method... however when I try to do a simple 'GET' request - I get a 405 error (bad method).

I tested the link in DHC, and the link is fine.

Here's my method:

```
    public JSONObject getClientByDeviceId (String link) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //            conn.setDoOutput(true);
    //            conn.setDoInput(true);
    //            conn.setUseCaches(false);
    //            conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    //            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.close();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            Log.e("conn", "Error code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            conn.disconnect();

            JSONObject returnedObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

            if (returnedObject != null) {
                Log.e("conn", "If 400, this is the object gained: " +     returnedObject.getString("Message"));
            } else {
                Log.e("conn", "didn't get any JSON object");
            }

            conn.disconnect();
            return returnedObject;

        }
        else {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            Log.e("conn", "GREAT SUCCESS !!: " + conn.getResponseCode());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            conn.disconnect();

            JSONObject returnedObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

            return returnedObject;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Normally I would say that this problem is caused by trying to do a 'GET' request in a 'POST' URL. But without the two HttpGet and HttpPost classes I don't really know where to turn, all the properties that are commented out are like that because I tried them in the POST request and now I deleted one by one to try to get the method to work.

Any ideas ? or reference to an updated guide on how to properly use that HttpURLConnection class, since I couldn't find one.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried it on Postman?

Comment: Yes, and also in DHC (Another Chrome extension) - they are not returning a 405 error

Comment: Then ask your php developer who is working on this web service.

Comment: Even though when I use the 'old' HttpGet I get positive results ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, apparently this code needed to be removed:

```
OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.close();
```

I guess it was because I gave a GET URL and put that outputStream in my code and that caused the issues.

I still however don't understand why I got the "405: method GET not allowed" whereas I think I should have gotten the opposite: "POST" not allowed...

Anyway that is my solution, thanks a lot for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 405 is caused by bad method call (Method not Allowed). That means you called GET method on POST request or vice-versa. You should add handling for you GET method on your Web-Service to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still reaching here from a search engine, my solution was similar - 
I removed the line "conn.setDoOutput(true);" (or set it to false)